# dompdf not rendering images from the server but is rendering from external source

Tags: php, image, pdf, codeigniter-2, dompdf

I'm trying to figure this out for the last few days now and come up with nothing.

I have dompdf working on my server and its creating the pdf fine. The only issue is its not rending the images I send to it. I have DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE set to TRUE, tmp folder is writable and get_file_contents is turned on.

Now the sample that you get in the dompdf folder renders the remote images fine it just seems to be images file from my server that's causing the issue.

I've tried absolute and relative urls.

I'm running this through codeigniter, and its the beta version 0.6.0.

This is my helper:

```
   function create_pdf($html, $filename, $stream=TRUE) 
   {
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    } else {
        write_file("./pdf_written_files/$filename.pdf", $dompdf->output());
    }
}
```

My controller function:

```
function pdf($id)
{
    if($id !== NULL)
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('create_pdf','text'));

        $result = $this->product_model->order_by('order')->get_by(array('id' => $id))? : NULL;
        $collection = $this->collection_model->my_collection($result->id);
        $range = $this->range_model->my_range($result->id);
        $result->collection = $collection;
        $result->range = $range;
        $this->_data['content'] = $result;
        $html = $this->load->view('created_pdf', $this->_data, TRUE);
        create_pdf($html, $result->title);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no input found';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is php-GD installed on the server ? What does dompdf/www/setup.php from say ? (navigate to in from your browser, like here http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/setup.php).

Comment: It would also help to see a sample of what `$html` holds. Specifically, what do you mean when you say that you have tried both absolute and relative URLs? Since you're using `$dompdf->load_html()` URLs without a domain will be relative to the PHP file or the operating system root (for URLs that begin with "/").

Answer (score 4):

Your image link must use the relative path from your web folder. Example, if your web folder is in /var/www/html/myweb and your image in your CI folder is in assets/images (in the same level as application folder), you just write the relative path : assets/images/imgname.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, no images were displaying for me - background images and inline ones. I had to set `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` to `true` in your config `dompdf_config.inc.php`

Just note the security risk if you have this enabled along with `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$dompdf->load_html($html);
```

if this is not working then change method from **set** to **set_option**