# Auto Print an Excel file from the web

Tags: javascript, php, windows, excel, printing

To explain a bit about the issue I have.

I have a system that generates excel based shipping labels.

We're changing the approach to create them and now we're looking for a way to print them as fast as possible.

The ideal result would be a button on the website which right after being clicked just triggers a local printer (user side of course) and prints straight away from the default printer no dialogs or anything.

Right now I've found two possible approaches to this.

1 - Windows software that auto prints when a file enters a specific folder:

I've found many of these and they work pretty good, the issue is that none of them is able to print xlsx files, only txt and pdf.

2 - A Windows macro recorder that right clicks / prints the excel file:

Its actually amazing the speed of the printout if you right click / print an excel file, opens excel prints on defaults settings and closes. Then the file should be auto deleted.

I haven't found any software that can do this properly, I found AutoIt but I'm not sure if its what I'm looking for.

My ideal solution would actually be based on PHP / Javascript / Ajax

But I haven't found not even a clue on doing such a thing with an excel file.
I know it's doable with pdf files opening them on a new window and using js window.print()

Yet I would really like to use the xlsx format due to the great control I have over them using the PHPexcel library.

There is likely a new much better approach to this that I'm probably missing.

Thanks for any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

Would rendering your Excel file as PDF serverside, then sending that to the client for printing be a potential solution? If so, the following may be of use:
[PHPExcel Save PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599221/phpexcel-save-pdf)
and
[How to configure phpexcel for pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409494/how-to-configure-phpexcel-for-pdf)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I wasn't aware that PHPExcel had the ability to save as PDF using an external library, I'll try this and get back with results.

Comment: This solution wasn't the way to go, my excel file has images that are important as shipping labels, and the PDF rendering from PHPExcel seems to loose images when converting.

Comment: Are they all images or just a few, and how are they linked?

Absolute URL's are blocked by default, but you can override them with a config setting.

The first answer here may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808488/dompdf-not-rendering-images-from-the-server-but-is-rendering-from-external-sourc